# Virtualbox two networks slow

Tags: networking, virtualbox, http, ruby-on-rails

I am running an Ubuntu server guest on Win 7 guest, and am running a webrick server (RoR dev).

If I have just a host-only network, everything works fine and the browser response is instant. However, if I add a second network (NAT), so that the server can connect to the internet (for various updates etc.), the host-to-guest access gets really slow. I can't use the bridge connection.

I am using the port 3000 (RoR Webrick server) and connecting to the guest via internet browser on this port (eg http://192.168.56.102:3000).

Any idea, what could be causing this? If I ping the IP from host console, I get < 0ms.

Here are the settings (relevant info is in english; `Povoleno vše` is `Everything is allowed`):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that works on [Jose Gonzalvo's site](http://nowfromhome.com/virtualbox-slow-network-from-windows-host-to-linux-guest/):

Edit the value in ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.X-pXXX/lib/ruby/1.9.X/webrick/config.rb from:

```
:DoNotReverseLookup => nil,
```

to

```
:DoNotReverseLookup => true,
```

Many thanks to Jose for the answer!

Comment: I'm not using rvm, but found the config file in /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/config.rb. Is there a way to make this change without editing a global config file?